# Modify Abstract syntax tree eclipse cdt C code

Tags: java, eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a c code like this

```
static S16 test_1603b( const S16 *,  const S16 * );
```

I want to edit this code pragmatically to be something like this

```
static S16 test_1603b( const S16 *varName,  const S16 *varName );
```

So what I did I used Eclipse CDT plugin outside the eclipse, and I have successfully extracted the Abstract syntax tree(AST) and visited all the method parameter declaration, but I can not found any way to rewrite the AST again with the new modification, My Code snippet:

public class RuleChk extends AbstractRule {

```
public RuleChk(IASTTranslationUnit ast) {
    super("RuleChk", false, ast);
    shouldVisitDeclarations = true;
    shouldVisitParameterDeclarations = true;
}

@Override
public int visit(IASTParameterDeclaration parameterDeclaration) {
    if (!parameterDeclaration.getRawSignature().startsWith("void")) {
        if (parameterDeclaration.getDeclarator().getName().getRawSignature().equals("")) {

            IASTDeclarator oldDec = parameterDeclaration.getDeclarator();

            //Create New Declarator Node
            INodeFactory factory = ast.getASTNodeFactory();
            IASTName name = factory.newName("varName".toCharArray());             
            IASTDeclarator declarator = factory.newDeclarator(name);
            declarator.setParent(oldDec.getParent());
            declarator.setInitializer(oldDec.getInitializer());
            declarator.setName(name);
            declarator.setNestedDeclarator(oldDec.getNestedDeclarator());
            declarator.setPropertyInParent(oldDec.getPropertyInParent());

            //get the rewriter
            final TextEditGroup editGroup = new TextEditGroup("FakeGroup");
            ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
            rewriter.replace(declarator,oldDec,editGroup);
            rewriter.rewriteAST();
        }
    }
    return super.visit(parameterDeclaration);
  }
}
```

After Debugging I found the org.eclipse.cdt.internal.formatter.ChangeFormatter#formatChangedCode, when it try to get the

```
ICProject project = tu.getCProject();
```

It throws a null pointer exception because the TransionUnit (tu) is being null from the beginning of the whole application,

ANY IDEAS GEEKS!

Comment: Where are you getting the `IASTTranslationUnit` from? Usually you get it via `ITranslationUnit.getAST()`, which means having an `ITranslationUnit`...

Comment: `IASTTranslationUnit translationUnit = GCCLanguage.getDefault().getASTTranslationUnit(fileContent, info, emptyIncludes, null, opts, log);`
I am running the cdt parser outside the Eclipse as a standalone project, I am using intellij, I tried this code
 `IPath ipath= new Path(path);
        IFile file= ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFile(ipath);
        ITranslationUnit tu= (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(file); `
but also fail because ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace() always throws exception says workspace is closed:
@HighCommander4

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the CDT infrastructure, including `ASTRewrite`, is not designed to run outside of an Eclipse project / workspace.

What you generally need to do in cases like this is:

- Create an Eclipse workspace. If you don't otherwise need an Eclipse workspace, you can create a temporary one and delete it when you're done.
- Create a CDT C project inside your workspace.
- Make sure the code you want to process is part of the project. If the files are contained inside the project's directory tree, then this happens automatically. Otherwise, you can set up a "linked folder" in the project to refer to a location outside of the project's directory tree.
- Depending on what your refactoring needs, you may need to run CDT's indexer on the project.
- Get an `ITranslationUnit` representing the file you want to process (similar to what you wrote in your comment).
- Get the `IASTTranslationUnit` from the `ITranslationUnit`.

The first four steps can be done manually, or automatically using Eclipse APIs.

Comment: Very good explanation, but could you guide me how to do the first two steps by code?, As the ResourcePlugin always be null?

Comment: I have managed to do the above by creating an eclipse c project and adding file in it, but unfortunally the code above doesn't rewrite the AST, Anything missing??????

Comment: `IASTDeclarator oldDec = parameterDeclaration.getDeclarator();
//Create New Declarator Node
INodeFactory factory = ast.getASTNodeFactory();
IASTName name = factory.newName("varName".toCharArray());
name.setBinding(oldDec.getName().getBinding());
name.setParent(oldDec.getName().getParent()); name.setPropertyInParent(oldDec.getPropertyInParent());
ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
rewriter.replace(name,oldDec.getName(),null);
rewriter.rewriteAST();`

Comment: @MostafaHassan It's hard to tell what is missing based on a small code fragment. I would suggest posting a complete example to the [CDT mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/cdt-dev), and people should be able to help there.

Comment: @MostafaHassan: Btw. I haven't forgotten about your other question (how to create workspace and project from code), but I need to research it myself and haven't had the time yet.

Comment: Thanks for your support, I was able to fix the issue by calling change#perform method ` //make the changes      
         ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ast);
         rewriter.replace(oldNode,newNode, null);
         Change c = rewriter.rewriteAST();
   c.perform(new NullProgressMonitor());`

Comment: @MostafaHassan: Sorry for the late reply. It looks like creating a workspace requires creating an Eclipse "application". See [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html#exercise-creating-an-eclipse-rcp-application) for an example. The resulting application will automatically create a workspace upon startup, and it can be accessed via `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()`.

Comment: @MostafaHassan: Creating a project involves the APIs  `IWorkspaceRoot.getProject()` followed by `IProject.create()`. Finally, to make the project a C/C++ project, `CoreModel.create(IProject)` needs to be used.